# Why is my while loop running even when the condition is false?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have been learning for one week and am making a hangman game to practice. I have a while loop to run when the player has more than one life and there are more letters to guess. However, when I test the game and purposely run out of lives, the loop still runs and returns a statement that I only want to return if lives are > 1.

```
def play():
    lives = 6
    random_word = str(random.choice(words))            
    letters_in_random_word = 0                          
    for letter in random_word:
        letters_in_random_word += 1                    
    already_guessed_list = []                            
    for letter in random_word:
        print("_", end='')                              
    while lives > 0 and letters_in_random_word > 0:       
        # more letters to be guessed
        get_guess = input("\nGuess a letter here: ")     
        if get_guess in already_guessed_list:            
            print("\nYou already guessed this letter. Please guess a different letter.")
        else:
            already_guessed_list.append(get_guess)      
            for letter in get_guess:
                if letter in random_word:
                    letters_in_random_word -= 1 * random_word.count(letter)    
                    print("\nThat letter is in this word. You have", lives, "lives left.")
                if get_guess not in random_word:
                    lives -=1                               
                    print("\nThat letter is not in this word. You have", lives,
                          "lives left. Use them wisely")
            for letter in random_word:
                if letter in already_guessed_list:      
                    print(letter, end = '')
                else:
                    print("_", end = '')
            if lives == 0:
                print("\nOut of lives. The word was", random_word)
            elif letters_in_random_word == 0:
                print("\nYou guessed the word correctly.")

play()
```

update: I changed the code to this and now am getting the desired result.

```
import random
from words import words


def play():
    lives = 6
    random_word = str(random.choice(words))
    letters_in_random_word = 0
    for letter in random_word:
        letters_in_random_word += 1
    already_guessed_list = []
    for letter in random_word:
        print("_", end='')
    while lives > 0 and letters_in_random_word > 0:
        print("\nYou have", lives, "lives left. Use them wisely")
        # more letters to be guessed
        get_guess = input("\nGuess a letter here: ")
        if get_guess in already_guessed_list:
            print("\nYou already guessed this letter. Please guess a different letter.")
        else:
            already_guessed_list.append(get_guess)
            for letter in get_guess:
                if letter in random_word and lives > 0:
                    letters_in_random_word -= 1 * random_word.count(letter)
                    print("\nThat letter is in this word.")
                if get_guess not in random_word and lives > 0:
                    lives -=1
                    print("\nThat letter is not in this word.")
            for letter in random_word:
                if letter in already_guessed_list:
                    print(letter, end = '')
                else:
                    print("_", end = '')
            if lives == 0:
                break
            if letters_in_random_word == 0:
                print("\nYou guessed the word correctly.")
    print("\nOut of lives. The word was", random_word)
    
play()
```

Comment: _when I test the game and purposely run out of lives, the loop still runs and returns a statement that I only want to return if lives are > 1_ What statement is that?

Comment: @JohnGordon    

That letter is not in this word. You have 0 lives left. Use them wisely
___p
Out of lives. The word was shop... If lives are 0, I expect my while loop to break and print a different statement ("out of lives. the word was (word)")

Comment: That print statement does not depend on the number of lives you have left, so of course it prints.

Comment: It might be a better design to print just `That letter is not in this word`, and move `"You have", lives, "lives left. Use them wisely"` to the top of the loop so it only prints when you have some lives remaining.

Comment: Why not just put a `break` in your `if lives == 0` to break out of the `while loop` when that condition is met?

Comment: @MichaelS. Thank you for this recommendation.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you for your advice I have fixed my issue and now can play hangman successfully.